# jQuery draggable with full-width container

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a parent div-container (full-screen width) including a draggable list of floated images (width of 5 images in a row is 4086px;). Something like this:

```
<div id="dragzone">
  <div id="draglist">
  <!-- BEGIN first row -->
  <img src="#" alt="" />
  <img src="#" alt="" /> [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks:

```
#dragzone{
background: #fff;
height: 630px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}    
#draglist{
width:4086px;
height: 630px;
cursor: move;
}    

draglist img {
float: left;
}
```

The draggable area is initialised with:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#dragzone" ).draggable({
        containment : 'parent',
        cursor: 'move'
        });
}); 
</script>
```

^ Unfortunately the above code does not working for me. Unless the "draglist" should not leave nor vanish within the parent container, it otherwise has to be draggable on the x-axis.

If I remove the containment option, the area will be draggable, but disappears being dragged outside the zone`s borders (both axes).

To be concreate at all: The image-list should not be draggable on the y-axis, but moveable on the x-axis, stopping automatically at the end of the list.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thanks Jay

Comment: I don't get it, what do you want to move? and from? and to? What's the size of each image? Do you want to drag the entire `#draglist` up and down or a single image?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you would want to use [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) rather than the *Dragable*, but I still don't get the code idea, here's an example that you should help us "seeing" your code better --> [JsBin example](http://jsbin.com/ojavac/edit#javascript,html,live)